# Is red wire used for earth in very old German machine mains plug?

Tags: electrical, grounding, cord-and-plug

Which is neutral and which is earth?

It seems that Black = Live, Grey = Neutral, Red = Earth

Was this assignment common in 1960?

How can I be sure?

Comment: To identify which one is the protective earth, just beep between the metal case and the wires. One should have a “zero” resistance to the chassis. That’s the PE. Live vs neutral won’t matter if there was no switch and no fuse. If a fuse is present, treat the fused circuit as live. If no fuse but a switch, then treat the switched circuit as live. That’s about it. Good luck!

Comment: From [here](https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/german-wiring-code.2249728/) **Jun 4, 2012
#5
Germany currently is using the international Electrical Commissions Coding: Neutral Blue, Line Brown (older Black), Ground is Green/Yellow.

The old system was (easy to identify if Red wire present or no Green/Yellow):
Line Black, Neutral Gray, Ground Red**   

Be sure by measuring the ground lead with a multimeter.

Comment: Old German equipment has used red for negative, see this exhibit from the clock museum https://www.dropbox.com/s/wme4n2thhyap100/Germany%202013%20069.JPG?dl=0

Comment: @Martin  That might be using DC power.  AC does not usually use + or - sign.